# How can the multivariate linear regression be linear in nature?

Tags: math, machine-learning, linear-regression

As per my limited knowledge, linear functions have only two variables  which define it, namely x and y.

However, as per multivariate linear regression,

```
h(x)=(theta transpose vector)*(x vector)
where theta transpose vector = (n+1)x1 vector of parameters
      x vector = input variables x0, x1, x2 ....., xn
```

There are multiple variables involved. Does it not change the nature of the graph and consequently the nature of the function itself?

Comment: If the answer has been helpful, kindly accept it (answers take up valuable time for respondents) - thanks

Answer (score 3):

> linear functions have only two variables which define it, namely x and y

This is not accurate; the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_function) of a linear function is a function that is linear in its independent variables.

What you refer to is simply the special case of only one independent variable `x`, where

```
y = a*x + b
```

and the plot in the (x, y) axes is a straight line, hence the historical origin of the term "linear" itself.

In the general case of k independent variables `x1, x2, ..., xk`, the linear function equation is written as

```
y = a1*x1 + a2*x2 + ... + ak*xk + b
```

whose form you can actually recognize immediately as the same with the multiple linear regression equation.

Notice that your use of the term *multivariate* is also wrong - you actually mean *multivariable*, i.e. multiple independent variables (`x`'s); the first term means multiple *dependent* variables (`y`'s):

> Note that multivariate regression is distinct from multivariable
>   regression, which has only one dependent variable.

([source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_statistics))

Comment: Thank you so much, but I'm sorry but i am more confused now. Can you please suggest some links i can can refer to?

Comment: @AsmaRahimAliJafri the links I have provided should be a good start